# Comparing Strings in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, I'm writing a program that reads code from a file, and classifies each part of it as an identifier, bracket, keyword, etc..

I'm doing this using if else statements, it works fine except with brackets and semicolons.

for example `if(a== "=" ) cout << "a is the equal operator"` works, but `if(a== ";" ) cout << "a is a semicolon"` doesn't. I also tried using the compare method, it didn't work either.

Can someone please tell me why that's happening?

Thanks

```
void checkString(string a)

        if(a=="("){
                cout << "RPAR: " << a + "\n";
        }

        else if(a==")"){
                cout << "LPAR: " << a + "\n";
        }

        else if(a.compare("{") == 0){
                cout << "LBRAC: " << a + "\n";
        }

        else if(a=="}"){
                cout << "RBRAC: " << a + "\n";
        }

        else{
                cout << "IDENTIFIER: " << a + "\n";
        }
}

int  main (){

    std::vector<string> STRINGS;
    string STRING;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("m.c");
    while(getline(infile,STRING,' ')){
            STRINGS.push_back(STRING);
    }

    infile.close();
    for(int i=0; i<STRINGS.size(); i++){
            checkString(STRINGS[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If a is a bracket or a semicolon the program prints IDENTIFIER: {.

Comment: Which type is `a`? Show the declaration.

Comment: How can we possibly help you based on what you've posted? We don't know what `a` is or what value it contains. All you've posted are two *extremely* trivial if statements which are syntactically valid.

Comment: ... or what "doesn't work" means... or what "the compare method" is...

Comment: a is a string, my code is inside a method checkString(string a).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a **complete**, **short** program that demonstrates the problem you are having. For more information about this debugging technique, see http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: @IyadAbilmona: Are you sure you are using double quotes or single quotes (`"` vs `'`) consistently in both cases?

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/vbZz9O), the program you describe works correctly. Rather than *describe* a program to us, please *show* us a program (preferably a short one).

Comment: I edited the question to include the code.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, please post a **short**, **complete** program that demonstrates your problem. Your code was neither short nor complete. As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/CJqmJq) it also doesn't demonstrate the problem you describe. If you are having trouble reducing your program to its essential bits, see http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: Well i added the main method to it, now its the whole code. I removed unnecessary if statements to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with `getline(infile,STRING,' ')`.

What happens if your code hits a `\n`, `\t`, etc? It will be extracted together with your token and you will end up with a string such as `";\n"`, which is not the same as `";"`

Either change the logic that you use to tokenize your file:

```
std::ifstream fin("m.c");
while (fin >> STRING ){
   STRINGS.push_back(STRING);
}
fin.close();
```

Or [trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring) your string.

---

**Update:**

And keep in mind that this kind of tokenizer will only work if your tokens are separated by whitespaces (`return 0 ;` will work as expected, `return 0;` will be tokenized to `return` and `0;`)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a is a c string then I would look into using the [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) method. If they are strings under the `#include <string>` header. I would look into [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)