# Why am I not parsing properly?

Tags: c++

For one of my C++ assignments, I have to parse sentences like the following:

```
SET a = 10
SET b = a
PRINT b
```

To parser these statements, I used the following code:

```
vector<string> stringSplitter(istringstream& tmp) {
vector<string> tokens;  
string str;
while(tmp.good()) {
    tmp >> str;
    tokens.push_back(str);              
}
return tokens;
}
```

For error checking I want to ensure the SET command has only 4 tokens and PRINT statements have only 2 tokens. So corresponding conditions that I have when I check a SET command and a PRINT command:

```
if (tokens.size() != 4) {
cerr << "Error in Line "<< lineNumber <<":Invalid format\n";
return -1;
}
```

and

```
if (tokens.size() != 2) {
cerr << "Error in Line "<< lineNumber <<":Invalid format\n";
return -1;
}
```

The problem I am having is that it works for "SET a = 10" and "PRINT a"
Where as it doesn't work if have have a white space at the end of the sentence like "SET a = 10 " and "PRINT a    "

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: there is a SO post on trimming whitepace from std::string here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
while ( tmp >> str )
```

`tmp.good()` only says whether there's anything left at all.  You want to know whether getting another string out of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator uses spaces  for tokenizing, so you don't get what you want if spaces are ommitted around `=`.

Instead use a more advanced function to split.

Comment: This is probably correct in the general case, but it appears the OP's grammar is pretty strict. The OP also appears to *want* the tokenizing features of `>>`.