# palindrome and mirrored string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i'm writing a code that read lines of string and check if it's mirrored, palindrome or mirrored palindrome
the problem is that it's always displaying wrong value's for inputs except the last one

**Sample Input:**

```
NOTAPALINDROME 
ISAPALINILAPASI 
2A3MEAS 
ATOYOTA
```

**Code:**

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<string>
  #include<vector>
  using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(const string &s)
{
    for(int i=0,j=s.length()-1;i!=j;i++,j--)
    {
        if(s[i]!=s[j])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
char get_mirror(const char &c)
{
    switch(c)
    {

    case 'A':return c;
    case 'E':return '3';
    case 'H':return c;
    case 'I':return c;
    case 'J':return 'L';
    case'L':return 'J';
    case'M':return c;
    case 'O':return c;
    case 'S':return '2';
    case 'T':return c;
    case'U':return c;
    case'W':return c;
    case'X':return c;
    case'Y':return c;
    case'Z':return '5';
    case'1':return c;
    case'2':return 'S';
    case'3':return 'E';
    case'5':return 'Z';
    case'8':return c;
    default: return'-1'; 

    }
}
 bool is_mirrored(const string &s)
 {
     for(int i=0,j=s.length()-1;i!=j;i++,j--)
     {
         if(get_mirror(s[i])!=s[j])
         {
             return false;

         }
     }
     return true;

 }

int main()
{
    vector<string>cases;
    vector<string>::iterator pt;
    string temp;
    while(getline(cin,temp))
    {
        cases.push_back(temp);

    }
    for(pt=cases.begin();pt!=cases.end();pt++)
    {
        cout<<*pt<<"    "<<is_palindrome(*pt)<<"   "<<is_mirrored(*pt)<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output if many strings:**

```
NOTAPALINDROME
ISAPALINILAPASI
2A3MEAS
ATOYOTA
^Z
NOTAPALINDROME     0   0
ISAPALINILAPASI     0   0
2A3MEAS     0   0
ATOYOTA    1   1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Output if one string:**

```
2A3MEAS
^Z
2A3MEAS    0   1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Could be unrelated, but try i<j instead. i!=j doesn't work when length is even.

Comment: Could you show us what the output is for the sample input you gave?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile `'-1'` is not a valid character.

Comment: What is this getMirror function?? so many letters (all letters of the last input word) return their own value and not mirror value? and so many letters are missing

Comment: The perfect opportunity to learn to use the debugger...

Comment: Visually, there's no reason for it to give the wrong results, which makes me suspect an invisible culprit.  I'm going to blame whitespace.  Dukeling's right about getting to know your debugger.  Set a breakpoint, look at each string, and I bet you'll see some trailing whitespace in all but the last input.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, I would say `i <= j` in the mirrored case so that `5` is not a mirrored palindrome and `A` is.

Comment: @idoo some letters are mirrored by it self 
The missing letters are letters with no mirror value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input seems to have additional whitespace that's wrecking your string checks.  Evidence of this is that your ouput for the many strings show 5 spaces instead of the 4 it should, except in the final line.  Either clean your input manually, or trim your input string in your program.  (See, e.g. [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring).)

Comment: I do agree with Aki Suihkonen and unkulunkulu's comments about tweaking your loop, though - your code as it is will fail on even length strings, though that's not the issue you're bringing up.

Comment: As an aside, it's very helpful when debugging string issues in any language to have delimiters that help you "see" whitespace.  E.g., if your output line was `cout<<'\''<<*pt<<'\''"    "<<is_palindrome(*pt)<<"   "<<is_mirrored(*pt)<<endl;`, the issue would have been immediately obvious.

Comment: yes,it's a white space problem
and i fixed the loop issue
thanks a lot ^_^