# Read from file C++

Tags: c++, fopen, fgets

I want to read only the IP's and printf them without blank spaces.Here is part of my code :

```
 char buffer[256]
    dns_serv = fopen("dns_servers.conf", "rt"));
    log = fopen("logfile", "at")) ; 
    if (!fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), dns_serv)) {
                break;
            }       

            if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
            if (buffer[0] == '\n') continue;

                if ((sockdns = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
                printf("Error\n");
                continue;
            }

            fprintf(log, "; %s - %s %s",buffer,argv[1], argv[2]);
```

This writes me on logfile :

```
; 141.85.128.1
 - google.com SOA
```

but i want to write it on the same line:

```
 ; 141.85.128.1 - google.com SOA
```

Where is my mistake?
Here is the dns_servers.conf:

```
# first example
141.85.128.1

# another
# 61.34.189.250
```

Comment: You should remove `'\n'` in `buffer`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you using standard C++ library, so:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

Next instead of:

```
dns_serv = fopen("dns_servers.conf", "rt"));
log = fopen("logfile", "at")) ;
```

write:

```
ifstream dns_serv("dns_servers.conf", std::ifstream::in);
ofstream log("logfile", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

Instead of:

```
if (!fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), dns_serv)) {
            break;
        }
```

write:

```
dns_serv.getline (buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (dns_serv.fail ()) break;
```

and finally instead of:

```
fprintf(log, "; %s - %s %s",buffer,argv[1], argv[2]);
```

write:

```
log << "; " << buffer << " - " << argv[1] << " " << argv[2]; // << endl;
```

Hope that it helped you :)
I know I ruined your C style, but little C++ discipline is not bad. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` places the `'\n'` (end-of-line) character into its input buffer. You should remove it (but beware of cases when `'\n'` is not placed into the buffer, e.g. when a line is too long for a given buffer and `fgets` stops reading before it reaches end of line, or because `fgets` reaches end of file).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you also output the `'\n'` at the end of the line contained in buffer (retrieved by fgets)

You need to remove it from the string, doing something like that:

```
  int len;

  len = strlen(buffer);
  buffer[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Of course it might be wise to add more checks. And maybe use a more OO approach using strings class.

Comment: You're welcome. Put my answer as problem solver to thank me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This code won't  include `'\n'` at end of the string.

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string line;
ifstream dns_serv ("dns_servers.conf");
ofstream log ("logfile");
if(dns_serv.is_open())
{
     while(dns_serv.good())
     {
          getline(dns_serv,line);
          if(line.at(0)=='#' || line.at(0)=='\n') continue;
          cout << line << endl;
          log << "; " << line << " - " << argv[1] << " " << argv[2] << endl;       
     }                       
}
dns_serv.close();
log.close();
```

in extra you can use some string trimming functions to remove extra white spaces.
see this [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Comment: Where does `ifstream`, `ofstream`, `getline`, etc. come from? The names aren't fully qualified and there's no `using` statement. It doesn't include the new line character but you don't say why. These things are important.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious thanks for the advice. i will keep that in my mind.