# How to effectively error check and evaluate a user input?

Tags: input, integer, basic

I am a very beginner programmer that is taking a class in school. We have a project where we are required to check if a user input is an integer, if it is not, we have to return an error message. Would anybody know how to do such a thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking input value is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728754/checking-input-value-is-an-integer)

Comment: You tagged BASIC as in the [BASIC language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC). Is this what you really want? If not, please tag the actual language in which you need your solution.

Comment: I downvoted the question because the original poster has not responded to the comments asked two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check input value is integer:

```
REM check if user input is integer
PRINT "Input";
INPUT X$
IF VAL(X$) THEN
    PRINT "Input is numeric value"
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if input is integer or fractional
EDIT: 05/07/2018 to include error checking

```
REM check if user input is integer
ON ERROR GOTO 100
PRINT "Input";
INPUT X$
IF VAL(X$) THEN
    IF INSTR(X$, ".") THEN
        PRINT "Input is fractional"
    ELSE
        PRINT "Input is numeric value"
    END IF
END IF
END
100 IF ERR = 6 THEN PRINT "Overflow"
END
```

Comment: Of course at this point you could check the input string for E or D which indicate exponents.