# cin.fail() not returning true

Tags: c++, cin

I am not sure if I understand cin.fail() correctly. I am trying to get it to return true when a user does not put in an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << cin.fail();

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I enter a non-integer (like 55.687) it returns 0(false) for the cin.fail(). I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing `number`. It will be `55`. The remaining text on `std::cin` will be `.687`.

Comment: It does print 55. I just don't understand how my code is any different than the first responder on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728754/checking-input-value-is-an-integer) question.

Comment: @ReaganCuthbertson _"EDIT: To address the comment below regarding input like 10abc, one could modify the loop to accept a string as an input. Then check the string for any character not a number and handle that situation accordingly. "_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream has not yet failed.

When `>>` reads into an integer, it stops as soon as it finds a character that can't be in the integer. In the case of `"55.687"`, that's the `'.'` character. So `cin >> number` reads `55` into `number`, and the `".687"` remains in the stream for future reading.

Given the same input

```
int main() {
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    cin >> number;
    cout << cin.fail();

    return 0;
}
```

The second `cin >> number` would fail because `'.'` cannot be parsed into an `int`. Example: https://ideone.com/iB3aNk