# How to validate combination of data type int and string?

Tags: c++

my code is:

```
int num;
string check = "true";
cin >> num;
if (cin.fail())
        check = "false";

cout << check;
}
```

I want to make sure the input is an integer only. When the input is like `r3` (non-digits followed by integer), the output is `false`. But when the input is like `3r` (digits followed by non-digits), the output is `true`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: use `getline`  then check if the whole string is a number.

Comment: @HattedRooster but getline cannot be used by int data type rite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking cin input stream produces an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728754/checking-cin-input-stream-produces-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

You can take input as a string and then check if the string is a number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string nstr;
    long n;
    char *end_point;
    std::cin >> nstr;
    n = std::strtol(nstr.c_str(), &end_point, 10);
    std::cout << (*end_point == '\0' ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to only check first character if it is a digit:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << (isdigit(s[0]) ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out 
123
true
$ ./a.out 
r1
false
$ ./a.out 
1r
true
```

If you would like to include signed numbers to yours test:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    bool unsigned_int = isdigit(s[0]);
    bool signed_int = (s[0] == '-' || s[0] == '+') && isdigit(s[1]);

    std::cout << (unsigned_int || signed_int ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out 
123
true
$ ./a.out 
+1xyz
true
$ ./a.out 
-98xxx
true
$ ./a.out 
abc
false
```

Comment: But doesn't OP want something like `1r` to show as `false`?

Comment: From what I can tell, if OP was fine with `1r` being false then their current method works just fine. I think they want to change it specifically because it doesn't work when there are non-digits after a number.

Comment: What about negative integer values ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    string input;
    string check = "true";

    cin >> input;
    if (input.length() != to_string(num = atoi(input.c_str())).length())
    {
        check = "false";
    }   

    cout << check;
    return 0;
}
```