# My code is stuck in an infinite loop in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to use a while loop to calculate the average of 3 inputted grades, but I can not enter the next grade as the loops keep on going without giving me the chance to enter the next grade.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    cout << "Enter grade: ";
    cin >> grade;
    
    while (grade != -1)
    {
        total = total + grade;
        count = count + 1;

        cout << "Enter next grade: ";
        cin >> grade;

    }
    int(average) = total / 3;
    cout << "Average: " << int(average) << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: What did you input for the first grade?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with integer and it works fine.

If you only take int as input, the best is to put something to check the input type. Use `cin.fail()` to check if user input anything other than int.

for example:

```
while(cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cout << "Please enter grade:"
    std::cin >> grade;
}
```

which I refer from https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/cpp/how+to+check+type+of+input+cin+c%2B%2B

and here as well [Checking cin input stream produces an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728754/checking-cin-input-stream-produces-an-integer)