# Is integer overflow that evil?

Tags: c++, overflow, undefined-behavior

Consider the following code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

using ll = long long;

int main() {
  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(0);
  int n, k;
  cin >> n >> k;
  vector<int> a(n);
  int sum = 0;
  for (auto &it : a) {
    cin >> it;
    sum += it;
  }
  cout << sum << "\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Input like (or anything greater than INT_MAX into k)

```
5 1234567891564
1 2 3 4 5
```

makes the program print

```
0
0 0 0 0 0
```

What actually happens? We don't use the value of `k` at all.

Comment: `cin >> k` fails

Comment: @user253751 Does this failure discard the next inputs?

Comment: The stream is in fail-state until you release it from bondage. And since you never actually check it (success/fail stream state), you never know it failed, and end up scratching you head on input that didn't in-fact happen.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728754/checking-cin-input-stream-produces-an-integer).

Comment: @migo101 no, the input is still there waiting for you to read it, which you don't. Your program keeps failing to read the same bad input over and over.

Comment: Side note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: @Jabberwocky Is it also a bad practice in competitive programming?

Comment: @migo101 it is bad practice, period. Don't do it. Whoever told you to do this should be banned from teaching C++ for the rest of his life

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think in competitive programming nobody cares as long as the code works and is fast. Until they try to compile it on Windows where the header file doesn't exist...

Comment: @user253751 on Windows or on the next version of gcc, clang or whatever

Comment: While this particular program might not be having issues with integer overflow, in gcc it is possible for an integer overflow to cause arbitrary memory corruption even in cases where the result of the calculation is simply stored into an automatic-duration `unsigned int` whose value would never be read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually no integer overflow in your code. Well in a wider sense it there is, but in a more narrow sense integer overflow would happen for example with:

```
int k = 1234567891564;
```

What actually happens is that in  this line

```
cin >> n >> k;
```

`operator>>` tries to read a `int` but fails. `1234567891564` is never actually assigned to `k`. When reading the input fails `0` will be assigned. Hence `k` comes out as `0`.

Once the stream is in an error state, all subsequent calls to `operator>>` will silently fail as well. You should always check the state of the stream after taking input. For example:

```
 if (std::cin >> n) {
     // input succeeded use the value 
 } else {
     // input did not succeed. 
     std::cin.clear(); // reset all error flags
 }
```