# How to grab values before space and after a space in c++

Tags: c++, string, std

For a project im working i want to grab text before the space and after the space.

to find the space i use the `isspace` method, any ideas how to get this done

Comment: Are you using std::string?

Comment: You are looking for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Comment: yes iam using std::string

Comment: i dont want to trim i want to grab and assign them to 2 new variables

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a string? Are you familiar with `substr`?

Comment: Give us an example of the input. You probably just need a `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like 0x499602D2 noted in the commments, you can use `std::stringstream` to read from string just as you would do with any other stream (like `std::cin`):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
    ss << "12 14";

    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Nice thing about this is that if you know how to work with `std::cin` or any other stream, you know how to work with `stringstream`, so you can adapt this example for you needs.

Comment: thank you for the awesome example will finish the code and comment the results too