# Removing whitespace from a string variable

Tags: c++, linux, unix

So I've looked up various functions and ways to remove whitespaces from strings, but none of them seem to be working for me. Here's what I have right now:

```
string filename = filenamet;
//remove all whitespace
//filename.erase(remove(filename.begin(), filename.end(), isspace), filename.end());
```

where filenamet is a string variable, and as is filename. I've double checked all my includes, so they don't seem to be the problem either. Here's the compiler error I'm getting:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void input(char*, char**)’:
test.cpp:256:68: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’ filename.erase(remove(filename.begin(), filename.end(), isspace), filename.end());
```

I've also tried it with remove_if without remove, but then I get this compiler error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void input(char*, char**)’:
test.cpp:256:71: error: ‘remove_if’ was not declared in this scope
     filename.erase(remove_if(filename.begin(), filename.end(), isspace), filename.end());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show the complete compilation error. What are your `#includes` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to trim std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OP seems to ask how to delete **all** spaces from a string, not how to trim spaces from the **ends** of a string. So, this is not a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: Thanks @cyber for editing my terrible formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
std::string remove_char(const std::string &input, char to_remove){
    std::string output;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
        if(input[i]!=to_remove)
            output+=input[i];
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you're creating a new string which doesn't contain `to_remove` while that function is supposed to *remove* `to_remove` from `input`.

Answer (score 3):

Always read your errors carefully!

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void input(char*, char**)’:
test.cpp:256:68: error: cannot convert 
    ‘std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}’ 
     to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ 
     to ‘int remove(const char*)’ 
     filename.erase(remove(filename.begin(), filename.end(), isspace), filename.end());
```

The issue is that the compiler thinks you're calling this [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) instead of this [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). I'm guessing the issue is that you simply forgot:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

because otherwise this line:

```
filename.erase(remove(filename.begin(), filename.end(), isspace), filename.end());
```

is the correct way to remove all spaces from the string `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this also:

```
   string::iterator iter = filename.begin();
   while ( iter != filename.end() )
   {
      if ( isspace ( *iter ) )
      {
         iter = filename.erase ( iter );
      }
      else
      {
         iter++;
      }
   }
```

I compiled and tested it so it should run fine.

Comment: I'm afraid that complexity of this might be up to O(n*n).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

// One of this two:

s.resize(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isspace) - s.begin());
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isspace), s.end());
```

## Explanation

`std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isspace)` overwrites beggining of the `s` using `s` with whitespace characters skipped. It does not change size of string, so if there was any whitespace, end of the `s` is going to be untouched and contain provious content, which is likely to be useless, so we trim it out using `std::string::resize` or [`std::string::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) (`std::remove_if` return pass-the-end iterator to new content, which I used to determine what to erase / what should be the new size of `s`).

Answer (score 0):

I just included below header file and everything worked for me.

```
#include <algorithm>
```