# how to remove the end newline characters using c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have a string which contains some newline character in the end. I am wondering how I could remove the new char using c++. The new line can be \r\n or \n

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring