# Unclear behavior with csv processing using getline

Tags: c++

I am having a little problem file processing a csv file. I am very new to C++ and trying to learn. It's probably a little thing I am overlooking but I have searched for answers online and cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I am trying to process a file that has multiple lines and comma separated values (no comma at the end of the line though if that makes a difference) -- of note, when I tried to post the text just now it did not include the paragraph breaks, I had to add that in manually-- not sure if that makes a difference

> Sale,11/9/14,11/9/14,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,-8.99
>
> Sale,10/4/14,10/5/14,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,-13.08
>
> Sale,10/3/14,10/5/14,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,-9.82
>
> Sale,10/2/14,10/3/14,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,-45.48
>
> Sale,8/21/14,8/22/14,AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTS,-9.99
>
> Sale,11/8/14,11/9/14,Amazon.com,-64.7
>
> Sale,10/1/14,10/2/14,APL* ITUNES.COM/BILL,-1.08
>
> Sale,9/15/14,9/16/14,APL* ITUNES.COM/BILL,-1.08

I tried using `getline` to get each line into a `stringstream` then parse out each of those lines by the comma delimiter using the code below:

```
ifstream file("test1.csv"); 
string value, line;
while (getline(file, line)) {
    stringstream   linestream(line);
    while (getline(linestream, value, ',')) {
        cout << "Value:   " << value << endl;
    } // while
    cout << "Done Procesing" << endl;
} // while
```

The problem I am getting is that for some weird reason after every 5th token of the comma delimited processing the word `“Sale”` overwrites the word `Value` and I cannot understand why. Would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: In the statement `while(getline(linestream,value,','))` you specify the delimiter to be a comma... there's no comma at the end of your line.

Comment: The input file probably contains DOS-style line-endings, which consist of a `\r\n` sequence. `getline()` reads the `\r` into `line`, and so the last `value` on each line includes the carriage return.

Comment: @user2899162, so it will read to EOF which in this case is the end of the current line, because `linestream` only contains a single line.

Comment: Whoops! Didn't type out my whole theory-- and if the file is written with a different end of line identifier, the end of the line might not be where we think it is. EDIT: I was way beaten to this.

Comment: @JonathanWakely this'll only happen if she's running in Unix (or unix-style environment); otherwise the environment should translate the endings

Comment: Trim the value before printing. This answer has a some elegant trim methods in C++. http://stackoverflow.com/a/217605/368818

Comment: @JonathanWakely: If the word `Value:` gets overwritten the line end sequence clearly is a `\n\r` pair. Otherwise the `\r` would cause an invisible carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description (but not visible in the text quoted) each line begins with a `'\r'` (carriage return) character. Some systems uses an end of line sequence. Windows typically uses `"\r\n"` (carriage return, line feed) which would be replaced by a single `'\n'` when opening the file in non-`binary` mode (i.e., when not passing the flag `std::ios_base::binary` when creating the stream). However, this replacement does *not* happen for a "\n\r" sequence.

You can easily verify this theory by replacing all `'\r'` characters before creating the `std::istringstream` (I slipped an extra `i` in there as I don't see why a read/write stream should be created):

```
std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), '\r', '@');
std::istringstream linestream(line);
```

With this change I would expect that the output of the first word of all but the first line would look like this:

```
Value:   @Sale
```

The easiest way to fix the problem is to simply skip leading whitespace when reading the line. The corresponding code excerpt would look like this:

```
std::ifstream file("test1.csv"); 
for (std::string line; std::getline(file << std::ws, line); ) {
    std::istringstream   linestream(line);
    for (std::string value; std::getline(linestream, value, ','); ) {
        std::cout << "Value:   " << value << '\n';
    } // for
}
std::cout << "Done Procesing\n";
```

The magic is the addition of `<< std::ws` when reading the line which simply removed all leading whitespace. The code also removes the [inappropriate use of `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/). If the first word on each line may include leading whitespace you would need a different approach, probably removing the `'\r'` characters before creating `linestream`, e.g., using

```
line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
```