# How to tokenize string by delimiters?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

I need to tokenize string by delimiters.

For example:

For `"One, Two  Three,,, Four"` I need to get `{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}`.

I am attempting to use this solultion https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680/1034253

```
std::vector<std::string> strToArray(const std::string &str,
                                    const std::string &delimiters = " ,")
{
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(delimiters.c_str());
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(str.c_str(), sep);

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (const auto &token: tokens) {
        result.push_back(token);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I get the error:

> boost-1_57\boost/tokenizer.hpp(62): error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
>   type is 'const char *const'

Comment: Does that error refer to one of the lines of code that you're showing us?

Comment: The solution you linked to does not use `c_str()`.  I'm assuming that boost requires that the argument is STL-centric, i.e. has a `begin()` iterator.

Comment: @DrewDormann That error refer to  tokenizer.hpp: template <typename Container>
    tokenizer(const Container& c,const TokenizerFunc& f)
      : first_(c.begin()), last_(c.end()), f_(f) { }

Comment: as @PaulMcKenzie, it wants std::string, not const char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(str.c_str(), sep);
```

To this:

```
boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tokens(str, sep);
```

Link:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm

The container type requires a `begin()` function, and a const char* (which is what `c_str()`) returns does not meet this requirement.

Comment: I think boost::char_separator<char> requires `char *`.

Comment: @Ufx - ok.  I removed the first line from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Boost's tokenizer is probably overkill for the task you describe.

[`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp430824992) was written for this exact task.

```
std::vector<std::string> strToArray(const std::string &str,
                                    const std::string &delimiters = " ,")
{
    using namespace boost;
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    split( result, str, is_any_of(delimiters), token_compress_on );
    return result;
}
```

That optional `token_compress_on` signifies that your `,,,` input shouldn't imply *empty string tokens* between those commas.

Comment: I've seen this solution. Can I stop adding tokens, when some size is reached?

Comment: @Ufx It's done in one shot, so if you want a maximum size for the returned vector, you would resize it before returning.

Answer (score 1):

Short way.

```
string tmp = "One, Two, Tree, Four";
int pos = 0;
while (pos = tmp.find(", ") and pos > 0){
    string s = tmp.substr(0, pos);
    tmp = tmp.substr(pos+2);
    cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of `boost` answers, so I thought I'd supply a non-`boost` answer:

```
template <typename OutputIter>
void Str2Arr( const std::string &str, const std::string &delim, int start, bool ignoreEmpty, OutputIter iter )
{
    int pos = str.find_first_of( delim, start );
    if (pos != std::string::npos) {
        std::string nStr = str.substr( start, pos - start );
        trim( nStr );

        if (!nStr.empty() || !ignoreEmpty)
            *iter++ = nStr;
        Str2Arr( str, delim, pos + 1, ignoreEmpty, iter );
    }
    else
    {
        std::string nStr = str.substr( start, str.length() - start );
        trim( nStr );

        if (!nStr.empty() || !ignoreEmpty)
          *iter++ = nStr;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> Str2Arr( const std::string &str, const std::string &delim )
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    Str2Arr( str, delim, 0, true, std::back_inserter( result ) );
    return std::move( result );
}
```

`trim` can be any trim function, I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring). It makes use of `std::back_inserter` and recursion. You could easily do it in a loop, but this sounded like more fun :)