# C++ DO loop being strange

Tags: c++, loops

First of all, here is my code:

```
string text;
do {
   cout << "Enter text: ";
   ws(cin);
   getline(cin, text);
} while (!text.empty());
// do stuff
```

**What I want my code to do ?**
- Check if the user input is empty ;
if the userinput = empty, loop to the beginning and he has to enter new text.
If userinput != empty, get out of the loop and continue the program.

**What is my code doing ?**
- When I enter a text, the loop start from the beginning and I have to retype a text.
- When I do not enter anything and just type enter, my program is indefinitely waiting and I need to Ctrl+C to exit.

Comment: Remember it's a do-while loop, not a repeat-until loop

Comment: You discard whitespace and never check the state of the stream.

Comment: don't you mean `while (text.empty())`

Comment: @Angew do loop : do the code at least one time then check the while, if the while condition is not fulfilled, then re-do the loop.

Comment: @Soren you answered my second problem.
Now the main one is that when I type "enter" the loop do not restart.

Comment: your call of the `ws` eats the enter so you never get to the end of the while loop by just typing enter -- you are better off not using the `ws` function and just strip the whitespace of the `text` before testing in the while

Comment: `ws` blocks and waits for input; much like `getline` does. It only returns when non-whitespace is entered. Furthermore, I think many implementations only pass on `cin` input after you pressed enter. In short, don't use `ws` on cin. You need other code to strip the whitespace off the input text.

Comment: Also see this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Comment: Oh so the problem is ws and I need another code to do what ws do and then what I want to will works ?

Comment: I was hinting at the same thing as Soren - that your condition was reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the link Soren I'll take a look ! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a `repeat-until`, but a `do-while` loop, use:

```
string text;
do {
   cout << "Enter text: ";
   ws(cin);
   getline(cin, text);
} while (text.empty());
//      ^^
```

Basically if the condition is `true` then it loops again, otherwise it breaks the loop. In your case it's looping if the string is not empty, and breaking the loop if the string is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that answer my second problem.
Now I need the loop to restart when the userinput is empty -- for example user directly type "enter"

Comment: When text is empty and when he just type enter.

Comment: @AmatErasu That's what the above code is doing. It will restart the loop when the user input is empty. How else would the user send an empty text without pressing "enter" while having no input entered?

Comment: I tried this code and when I type just enter on my keyboard, then program is not exiting nor reloading the loop.

Comment: If it doesn't exit, why do you think it's not reloading the loop?