# How to trim const wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

I have `const wchar_t*` looks like `"\n\t\t\t\tsomething\n\t\t\t\t"` and I want to get `"something"`. What is the most efficient way to do it?

[EDIT]
I've worked out something like this:

```
typedef wchar_t XMLCh

const XMLCh* trimTabs(const XMLCh* text)
{
string dest = XMLString::transcode(text);
dest.erase(remove(dest.begin(),dest.end(),'\t'), dest.end());
dest.erase(remove(dest.begin(),dest.end(),'\n'), dest.end());
return XMLStr(dest.c_str()).getXMLStr();
}
```

`XMLStr` class which is existing already in my project helped mi a lot. I hope it's good answer. XMLString is a class from Xercesc library.

Comment: If it's const and you want your result to be null-terminated, then you have no other choice than make a copy of the result string.

Comment: C or C++? Those are different languages with very different ways of going about it; pick one.

Comment: You're Right, @Angew . I've picked c++ ;)

Comment: You're returning a pointer to the contents of a temporary `XMLStr`. That's going to blow up. Pick C++, return a `XMLStr`. object.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your const wchar_t* to std::wstring, and then trim it using one of the methods from [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring). You cant trim `const wchar_t*`, it must be copied.

[edit]

additional comment to your updated question. With below function signature it is not possible to accomplish what you want.

```
const XMLCh* trimTabs(const XMLCh* text)
```

I dont know how the rest of your code looks like, but here the best you can do is to change to:

```
string trimTabs(const XMLCh* text)
{
string dest = XMLString::transcode(text);
dest.erase(remove(dest.begin(),dest.end(),'\t'), dest.end());
dest.erase(remove(dest.begin(),dest.end(),'\n'), dest.end());
return string(XMLStr(dest.c_str()).getXMLStr());
}
```

otherwise you are returning `const wchar_t*` to some temporary buffer which is undefined behaviur. I assume here your `XMLStr` is not managing memory in some global allocator.

Answer (score 0):

You will need new variable to store the characters, so first of all just iterate over your string and find the first and the last occurrance of non-whitespace character. You can use two pointers and iterate from the beginning and the end of a string. Then you can use this function to copy the string:

```
wchar_t* wcscpy (wchar_t* destination, const wchar_t* source);
```

You can find the description here:  [C++ Reference - wcscpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscpy/)