# How to specify field width properly

Tags: c++

I want to display output like this:

First Name: Max              Last Name: Payne
City: Brisbane               Phone Number: 155478635

I have tried with \t and setting field width using cout.width() and setw(), but this width gets changed and are not displayed in columns properly and depends on my input length.

My code is given below:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;



 class BillSys{

       char fname[20], lname[20], city[20], phone[11];

       public:

       void accept(){

             cout<<"Enter the name of the customer: ";
             cin>>fname>>lname; cout<<endl;
             cout<<"Enter city: ";
             cin>>city; cout<<endl;
             cout<<"Enter contact number: ";
             cin>>phone;
             cout<<endl<<endl;

      }

      void display(){

            cout<<"***Customer Details***"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"First Name: ";
            cout<<fname;

           //cout<<setw(10); 

           cout<<"\t";

           cout<<"Last Name: "<<lname;
           cout<<endl;

           cout<<"City: "; 
           cout<<city;
           cout<<"\t";

          //cout<<setw(10); 

          cout<<"Phone Number: "<<phone;
          cout<<endl;
      }

  };

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     BillSys obj;

     obj.accept();
     obj.display();
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try you search online for an example?

Comment: Use `printf` with formatting. `cout` is for students.

Comment: @i486 And I guess you are not a student, but a battle-hardened code veteran? :)

Comment: @Boris Yes, you guess. I am programmer from more than 25 years. Do you remember Windows 3.0 and do you know Win16 API?

Comment: @i486 Well at least I know why you think that "`printf` is for real programmers" :)

Comment: @i486 Rubbish. Using `std::cout` and `<<` is the idiomatic way to print to standard output in C++. The common conception that using low level stuff is better, is hardly progressive.

Comment: `cout` and `<<` are "demo" for beginners in C++. To show them example for predefined operators. And from students' years some people keep using it 10+ years later.

Comment: @i486 Again, utter subjective rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I would gather all the information in one `std::string` and then modify/trim the string. You might find some inspiration in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ and [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)