# OpenCV CommandLineParser Unspecified Params

Tags: c++, opencv, command-line-arguments

When using `cv::CommandLineParser`, is it possible to parse an arbitrarily long list of non-flag args?
For example:

```
> app -a -b=2 a.txt b.txt c.txt ...
```

I want to get access to *all* the non-flag "positional" args, without having to define a predefined number of them in the `keys` specification. This number is only determined by the caller of the app.

Comment: Will be an option for you to provide a parameter (e.g. `-N`) that specify the number of positional arguments? i.e. `app -a -b=2 -N=3 a.txt b.txt c.txt`?

Comment: No. That's not an option. The thing is that it seems like they are never parsed and by the time I may have the actual number it is too late since the positional args are specified at compile time.

Comment: Ok, I came up with a potential solution. Both options should fit your requirements. Option 2 doesn't require the extra parameter. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV `CommandLineParser` cannot handle a variable number of *positional* arguments. You can:

1. Pass an extra argument (e.g. `-N`) specifying the number of positional arguments;
2. Consider every argument that doesn't start with `-` to be a positional argument.

You can then make a custom command line parser with the same interface as `cv::CommandLineParser` able to handle a variable number of positional arguments.

**Option 1**

```
struct CustomCLP
{
    CustomCLP(int argc, const char* const argv[], const cv::String& keys, const String& positional_id)
    {
        String pos_key = "{" + positional_id + "|0|}";
        cv::CommandLineParser pos_clp(argc, argv, pos_key);
        _N = pos_clp.get<int>(positional_id);

        cv::String pos_keys = keys;
        for (int i=0; i<_N; ++i)
        {
            pos_keys += "{@pos" + to_string(i) + "||}";
        }

        _clp = new CommandLineParser(argc, argv, pos_keys);
    }

    ~CustomCLP()
    {
        delete _clp;
    }

    bool check() const {return _clp->check();}
    bool has(const cv::String& name) const {return _clp->has(name);}

    template<typename T>
    T get(const String& name, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp->get<T>(name, space_delete);
    }
    template<typename T>
    T get(int index, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp->get<T>(index, space_delete);
    }

    int n_positional_args() const { return _N;}

private:
    CommandLineParser* _clp;
    int _N;
};
```

You can specify the extra argument (e.g. `-N`) that specify the number of positional arguments. In the constructor, you parse this number, and create a *key* for each positional argument. Then you can use it as always.

**Option 2**

```
// SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976541/5008845
inline std::string trim(const std::string &s)
{
    auto  wsfront = std::find_if_not(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isspace);
    return std::string(wsfront, std::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), std::string::const_reverse_iterator(wsfront), std::isspace).base());
}

struct CustomCLP2
{
    CommandLineParser _clp;
    vector<std::string> pos_args;

public:
    CustomCLP2(int argc, const char* const argv[], const cv::String& keys) :
        _clp(argc, argv, keys)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            std::string s(argv[i]);
            s = trim(s);
            if (s[0] == '-') continue;

            pos_args.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    bool check() const { return _clp.check(); }
    bool has(const cv::String& name) const { return _clp.has(name); }

    template<typename T>
    T get(const String& name, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp.get<T>(name, space_delete);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get(int index, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << pos_args[index];
        T t;
        ss >> t;
        return t;
    }

    template<>
    cv::String get(int index, bool space_delete) const
    {
        return cv::String(pos_args[index]);
    }

    int n_positional_args() const { return pos_args.size(); }
};
```

In the constructor you save every argument that doesn't start with `-`. Then you can retrieve it as usual.

**Usage**

Note that the interface is consistent with CommandLineParser (a few methods like `about`, `getPathToApplication` are not available in this example, but it's easy to add them to the custom class).

Command line arguments are:

```
Option 1: -a -b=2 -N=3 a.txt b.txt c.txt
Option 2: -a -b=2 a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


struct CustomCLP
{
    CustomCLP(int argc, const char* const argv[], const cv::String& keys, const String& positional_id)
    {
        String pos_key = "{" + positional_id + "|0|}";
        cv::CommandLineParser pos_clp(argc, argv, pos_key);
        _N = pos_clp.get<int>(positional_id);

        cv::String pos_keys = keys;
        for (int i=0; i<_N; ++i)
        {
            pos_keys += "{@pos" + to_string(i) + "||}";
        }

        _clp = new CommandLineParser(argc, argv, pos_keys);
    }

    ~CustomCLP()
    {
        delete _clp;
    }

    bool check() const {return _clp->check();}
    bool has(const cv::String& name) const {return _clp->has(name);}

    template<typename T>
    T get(const String& name, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp->get<T>(name, space_delete);
    }
    template<typename T>
    T get(int index, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp->get<T>(index, space_delete);
    }

    int n_positional_args() const { return _N;}

private:
    CommandLineParser* _clp;
    int _N;
};

// SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976541/5008845
inline std::string trim(const std::string &s)
{
    auto  wsfront = std::find_if_not(s.begin(), s.end(), std::isspace);
    return std::string(wsfront, std::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), std::string::const_reverse_iterator(wsfront), std::isspace).base());
}

struct CustomCLP2
{
    CommandLineParser _clp;
    vector<std::string> pos_args;

public:
    CustomCLP2(int argc, const char* const argv[], const cv::String& keys) :
        _clp(argc, argv, keys)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            std::string s(argv[i]);
            s = trim(s);
            if (s[0] == '-') continue;

            pos_args.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    bool check() const { return _clp.check(); }
    bool has(const cv::String& name) const { return _clp.has(name); }

    template<typename T>
    T get(const String& name, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        return _clp.get<T>(name, space_delete);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get(int index, bool space_delete = true) const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << pos_args[index];
        T t;
        ss >> t;
        return t;
    }

    template<>
    cv::String get(int index, bool space_delete) const
    {
        return cv::String(pos_args[index]);
    }

    int n_positional_args() const { return pos_args.size(); }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    String keys =   
        "{a | | whatever a}"
        "{b | 1 | whatever b}";

    //CustomCLP clp(argc, argv, keys, "N");
    CustomCLP2 clp(argc, argv, keys);

    if (clp.has("a")) {
        cout << "Has <a>" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Doesn't have <a>";
    }

    int b = clp.get<int>("b");
    cout << "<b> : " << b << endl;

    int N = clp.n_positional_args();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << to_string(i) << ": " << clp.get<cv::String>(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like option 2 better, because it doesn't change `keys` which would require saving the usage string before modifying it.