# Map number between 1 and 12 to month name

Tags: c++

I need to make a program that displays a month based on the user input. For example, if the user inputs `8`, it will display `August`. I cannot use `if` statements or anything that checks for a condition. I also have to use the function `.substr()`. I have to use a string that contains all the months.

For example, `string months = "January...December";`

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: Since I have no feedback, give me another downvote so I can get the peer pressure badge...

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** Replaced the "user input check" `if` for a `try-catch` block in order to comply with OP restriction: "*I cannot use if statements*"

You could just format the "months" `string` to suit your needs. The longest month name is September (9 letters), so fill up "months" with spaces up to 9 letters for each month:

```
std::string months="January  February March    April    May      June     July     August   SeptemberOctober  November December ";
```

Then you could just use the user input as index for the `substr`, assuming user input will be between 1 and 12. i.e.:

```
input--;    // Indexes start at 0
input *= 9; // Scale it to word length

// Use substr as requested. Remember 9 is the max length of the month name
std::string selectedMonth = months.substr(input, 9);
```

If needed, you could trim the trailing whitespaces as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217605/5583153)

*Please take into account this is a didactic example to be easily understood, with plenty of room for improvement*. Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int input = 0;
    cin >> input;

    string months="January  February March    April    May      June     July     August   SeptemberOctober  November December ";

    input--;    // Indexes start at 0
    input *= 9; // Scale it to word length

    string selectedMonth;
    try
    {
        // Use substr as requested. Remember 9 is the max length of the month name
        selectedMonth = months.substr(input, 9);
    }
    catch (out_of_range &ex)
    {
        cout << "error: input must be in the range [1, 12]";
    }
    // Trim it before outputting if you must
    cout << selectedMonth;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And there goes another downvote without a comment. Care to explain why so I can improve the answer? I just provided a possible solution for what OP asked: no if's, must use .substr() and. have to use a string that contains all the months.