# remove_if last character from a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, stl

I would like to remove first and last brackets in passed by reference string. Unfortunately, I have difficulties with removing first and last elements conditionally.
I cannot understand why `remove_if` doesn't work as I expect with iterators.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VDMIB67704)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_wo_brackets(string& str){
    auto detect_bracket = [](char x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);};
    if (!str.empty()) 
    {
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, detect_bracket));
    }
    if (!str.empty()) 
    {
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.end()-1, str.end(), detect_bracket));
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str = "abc)";
    cout << str << endl;
    print_wo_brackets(str);
    cout << str << endl;


    string str2 = "(abc";
    cout << str2 << endl;
    print_wo_brackets(str2);
    cout << str2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
abc)
ac    <- HERE I expect abc 
(abc 
abc
```

Comment: This answer may be useful (also other answers may suit) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25385766/3807729

Comment: basically, remove_if does not change the size of the container. Instead it returns the new end. You have to update the string manually to reflect the change. Using it on the first character will probably make a mess of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If remove_if returns `end` iterator then you will try to erase nonexistent element. You should use `erase` version for range in both places:

```
void print_wo_brackets(string& str){
    auto detect_bracket = [](char x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);};
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, detect_bracket), str.begin() + 1);
    }
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        str.erase(std::remove_if(str.end()-1, str.end(), detect_bracket), str.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a valid answer, but in the example `end` points to letter `b` (as it's a typical pointer, most probably)

Comment: It remove UB but - you are right, this wont make your code run correct - other bugs still exists

Comment: @CronAcronis - first `str.erase` used wrong end iterator range, now it should work

Comment: You must also check for cases when no brackets are present, string is of length 1,...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
if (!str.empty()) 
{
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, detect_bracket));
}
```

you erase unconditionally.
`std::remove_if` returns iterator to the beginning of range "for removal". If there are no elements for removal, it returns end of range (`str.begin() + 1` in this case). So you remove `begin+1` element, which is `b`.

To protect from this problem you shouldn't probably do something more like:

```
if (!str.empty()) 
{
    auto it = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, detect_bracket);
    if(it != str.begin() + 1)
        str.erase(it);
}
```

I assume you simply want to check behavior of standard library and iterators, as otherwise check:

```
if(str[0] == '(' || str[0] == ')')
    str.erase(0);
```

is much simpler.

Comment: But in case of `str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end, detect_bracket));` it will remove all brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string without_brackets(std::string str, char beg = '(', char end = ')') {
    auto last = str.find_last_of(end);
    auto first = str.find_first_of(beg);

    if(last != std::string::npos) {
        str.erase(str.begin()+last);
    }
    if(first != std::string::npos) {
        str.erase(str.begin()+first);
    }

    return str;
}


using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << without_brackets("abc)") << endl
         << without_brackets("(abc") << endl
         << without_brackets("(abc)") << endl
         << without_brackets("abc") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/T2bZDe

result:

```
abc
abc
abc
abc
```

Comment: Nice solution, but not with `remove_if`

Comment: @CronAcronis - exactly. `remove_if` is the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments by @PeteBecker, `remove_if` is not the right algorithm here. Since you only want to remove the first and last characters if they match, a much simpler approach is to test `back()` and `front()` against the two parentheses `(` and `)` (brackets would be `[` and `]`)

```
void remove_surrounding(string& str, char left = '(', char right = ')')
{
    if (!str.empty() && str.front() == left)
        str.erase(str.begin());
    if (!str.empty() && str.back() == right)
        str.erase(str.end() - 1);
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2022355e2d4fa5de)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
void print_wo_brackets(string& str){
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    [&](char &c) { return (c == ')' || c == '(') && (&c == str.data() || &c == (str.data() + str.size() - 1));}), str.end());
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13bad92b364cc809)

By stating:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.end()-1, str.end(), detect_bracket));
```

You're evoking undefined behaviour.