# Remove punctuation from beginning and end of string c++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to remove punctuation specifically from the beginning and end of a string, while leaving contractions and possessives alone?

e.g "!wow!" would become "wow" and "can't" would stay "can't"

Comment: Certainly. It will, however, require code I'm afraid. How'd yours turn out? (I'm assuming not so well, otherwise you wouldn't be here). Perhaps post it *in your question* and we can see where the problem is?

Comment: This post may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25385766/3807729 not sure it qualifies as a duplicate or not.

Comment: I've tried erasing the character at the index, but that throws an error because the index is thereby empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with [`boost::trim_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.trim_hpp):

```
std::string a = "!wow!";
boost::trim_if(a, [](char c) { return std::ispunct(c); });
std::cout << a << '\n';
```

Outputs:

```
wow
```

Comment: Not too familiar with boost. Is there an article where I could learn more about using it in this context? Or is there a more universal option?

Comment: @bfriz_96 Nothing quite so elegant. You could [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) and [`find_last_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_not_of) and get the [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) between them

Comment: @bfriz_96 Here is an overview/tutorial for boost string algos: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html