# std::ptr_fun replacement for c++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using `std::ptr_fun` as follows:

```
static inline std::string &ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))));
    return s;
}
```

as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217605).

However this does not compile with C++17 (using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017), with the error:

```
error C2039: 'ptr_fun': is not a member of 'std'
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: And the error is....?

Comment: The error is: error C2039: 'ptr_fun': is not a member of 'std'

Comment: [edit] your full error message in the question

Comment: If MVS2017 supports it, I think you could simply do `std::not_fn(::isspace)`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You use a lambda:

```
static inline std::string &ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int c) {return !std::isspace(c);}));
    return s;
}
```

The answer you cited is from 2008, well before C++11 and lambdas existed.

Comment: Compiles perfectly and it's easier to understand than the 2008 solution. Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the 2008 answer with link to this one.

Comment: `s/int/unsigned char/`.

Comment: @T.C.: [`isspace` takes an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace). Not that this is in any way useful, but best to match the signature of the function in question.

Comment: No, `unsigned char` here is required for correctness, since `string` uses (possibly signed) `char`, but `isspace`'s argument must be representable as `unsigned char` if it's not `EOF`.

Comment: @T.C.: Whatever correctness problem would come from this function using `int` will come from `isspace`'s use of `int`. Or can you provide some code which would be OK if `isspace` were used directly but is wrong if there's an intermediate function?

Comment: Well, yes, OP's code has the same bug, but I don't see why a glaring bug should be left uncorrected. YMMV.

Comment: @T.C. I don't understand - `std::isspace()` takes an `int`. What difference does it make if the conversion to `int` happens into `isspace()` or into another function that just calls `isspace()`?

Comment: @Barry The point is that you aren't supposed to call any of the C character classification functions with a `char` or with a `char` converted  (directly) to `int`. You are supposed to call them with a `char` converted to `unsigned char` and then to `int`. The intermediary `unsigned char` conversion is necessary to correctly handle negative-valued `char`s.

Comment: @T.C. That's just a horrible interface then. Yay C.

Comment: It's worth noting that `std::isspace` takes (and returns) `int` because it's a C standard library relic from < 1990. When writing Actual C++™ you can `#include <locale>` and then use [`std::isspace(' ', std::locale("C"))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace), which as one might hope takes any character type and returns `bool`.

Answer (score 20):

Just use a lambda:

```
[](unsigned char c){ return !std::isspace(c); }
```

Note that I changed the argument type to `unsigned char`, see the [notes for `std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace#Notes) for why.

[`std::ptr_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun) was deprecated in C++11, and will be removed completely in C++17.

Answer (score 5):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun), `std::ptr_fun` is deprecated since C++11 and discontinued since C++17.

Similarly, [`std::not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) is deprecated since C++17.

So best don't use either, but a lambda (as explained in other answers).

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you might use [std::not_fn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn):

```
static inline std::string &ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
        std::not_fn(static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace))));
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer is similar to the already given answers in this thread. But instead of

```
int isspace(int c);
```

function from the standard `C` library, I am suggesting to use

```
bool isspace(char c, const locale& loc);
```

function instantiation from the standard `C++` library (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace), which is more type-correct. In this case you don't need to think about `char -> unsigned char -> int` conversions and about the current user's locale.

The lambda which searches for non-space will looks like this then:

```
[](char c) { return !std::isspace(c, std::locale::classic()); }
```

And the full code of `ltrim` function will look like this:

```
static inline std::string& ltrim(std::string& s) {
    auto is_not_space = [](char c) { return !std::isspace(c, std::locale::classic()); };
    auto first_non_space = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_not_space);
    s.erase(s.begin(), first_non_space);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use Lambda as suggested by Nicol Bolas but you can use auto and type will be deduced there, as follow:-

```
    static inline std::string &ltrim(std::string &s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto c) {return 
       !std::isspace(c);}));
    return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `std::isspace` with lambda instead of `std::ptr_fun`,

```
static inline std::string &ltrim(std::string &s) {
    str.erase(str.begin(), std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isspace(c);}));
    return s;
}
```

you can find more details about [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace#Notes)