# C++ : How to skip first whitespace while using getline() with ifstream object to read a line from a file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a file named "items.dat" with following contents in the order itemID, itemPrice and itemName.

```
item0001 500.00 item1 name1 with spaces
item0002 500.00 item2 name2 with spaces
item0003 500.00 item3 name3 with spaces
```

I wrote the following code to read the data and store it in a struct.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    string name;
    string code;
    double price;
};

item items[10];

void initializeItem(item tmpItem[], string dataFile);

int main() {

    initializeItem(items, "items.dat");
    cout << items[0].name << endl;
    cout << items[0].name.at(1) << endl;
    return 0;
}

void initializeItem(item tmpItem[], string dataFile) {

    ifstream fileRead(dataFile);

    if (!fileRead) {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not read file " << dataFile << endl;
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        while (fileRead >> tmpItem[i].code) {
            fileRead >> tmpItem[i].price;
            getline(fileRead, tmpItem[i].name);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

What I notice is the getline() reads the white space at the beginning while reading item name along with the content.

Output

```
 name1 with spaces
n
```

I want to skip the whitespace at the beginning. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of skipping the white-space, why not *trim* the string after reading?

Comment: But we will have to write a trim function by ourselves, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's easy and there are many examples all over the 'net (including quite a few here on SO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) IO manipulator can be used to discard leading whitespace.

A compact way to use it is:

```
getline(fileRead >> std::ws, tmpItem[i].name);
```

This discards any whitespace from the `ifstream` before it's passed to `getline`.

Comment: This worked. BTW does this work for trailing whitespaces too?

Comment: @AnjJo Are you talking about your `getline` call? Unfortunately `getline` reads the entire line until the default delimiter (a newline) or EOF. If there are trailing spaces you'll need to trim them.

Comment: How can i use std::ws to trim trailing whitespace?

Comment: @AnjJo In combination with `getline`? You can't, that reads everything up to but not including the newline. You'll need to use some string trimming code (search here on SO). `std::ws` is most useful in discarding whitespace left from a previous stream extraction (`>>`) operation.

Comment: @AnjJo This may help: [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216823/445976)