# how to prevent getline from getting an extra space for newline

Tags: c++, string, getline

I want to use `getline` for reading a `string` after taking an integer input with `cin`. But I'm being troubled with an extra space. Here is my code:

```
string y;
int x;
cin >> x;
getline(cin, y);
```

Say, for input: `"5 Hello World"`
Output comes: `"5"` as the integer & `" Hello World"` as the string.

Comment: cin is doing the right thing you should probably just trim the input string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Comment: yeah,        getline(cin>>ws,y); Just works fine