# trim matching characters from start or end of string c++

Tags: c++

I need to trim the beginning **or** end of a string, given a matching character.

My function definition looks:

```
void trim(std::string &s, char c, bool reverse = false);
```

The bool `reverse` flags whether to trim the beginning (false) or end (true) of the string.

For example:

```
s = "--myarg--";
trim(s, '-', false); // should set s to "myarg--"
trim(s, '-', true);  // should set s to "--myarg"
```

To trim the beginning (i.e. `reverse=false`), this works fine:

```
bool ok = true;
auto mayberemove = [&ok](std::string::value_type ch){if (ch != '-') ok = false; return ok;};
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), mayberemove), s.end());
```

The lambda just returns `true` for each character matching '-', up until the first occurrence of a non-matching character, and continues to return false thereafter. Here I've hard-coded the matching char to be '-', to make the code easier to read.

The trouble I am having is with trimming in reverse. This doesn't work - same as above, but with reverse iterators and ::base():

```
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), mayberemove).base(), s.end());
```

Instead, the line above trims all of the ending characters except for the first two.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard for you to plop all that into a [mcve]. Right now you say you are having problems with the reverse, but only offer up one like of the reverse code.

Comment: This answer may be of use (allows left and right trimming) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring/25385766#25385766

Comment: @rici that doesn't work. I don't see that remove has that construct, and if it did, it would remove all "-" characters from the entire string - which isn't what I was after.

Comment: @blair: Ok, that's true. What you really want to use is `find_if_not`).

Comment: You should not use a `bool` for the reverse parameter. It make the code harder to understand. Use an `enum class` or have multiple functions like `trim`, `trim_left` and `trim_right` instead. If not yet convinced, then read books on good coding practices.

Comment: @Phil1970 actually, I'm perfectly convinced, and you're exactly right. I'm trying to get away from bad habits like this - thanks for pointing it out. I'll split it into distinct functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string& trim( std::string& s, char c, bool reverse = false )
{
  return reverse
    ? s.erase( s.find_last_not_of( c ) + 1 )
    : s.erase( 0, s.find_first_not_of( c ) );
}
```

Comment: Function is defined to return `void`.

Comment: @Mark actually, apart from the return, that does work. I just tested it with a bunch of "-"s.

Comment: I'll probably go with this. I haven't seen those functions before. It seems to be perfectly concise, and I would guess very efficient.

Comment: @BlairFonville Aye, I didn't give it a good look at first, it's actually simple and clever.

Comment: Yes, oops, I always use a much more capable version than this, and shoe-horned it into OP's function signature. Thanks for the return type edit Mark!

Comment: Wholeheartedly approve of the return of the string. Instantly makes it way more useful, in an initialization, for example. In fact, I'd be tempted to `std::string trim(std::string s, char c, bool reverse = false)` so you don't trash the input string.

Comment: Actually, I do too. I return a reference in my actual implementation. I don't know why I changed it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I just figured it out. It looks like I needed to reverse the logic of the `mayberemove` lambda for the reverse case. So, this appears to work fine:

```
if (reverse) {
    bool notok = false;
    auto mayberemove = [&notok](std::string::value_type ch){if (ch != '-') notok = true; return notok;};
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), mayberemove).base(), s.end());
}
else {
    bool ok = true;
    auto mayberemove = [&ok](std::string::value_type ch){if (ch != '-') ok = false; return ok;};
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), mayberemove),s.end());
}
```

And that works. Now I just need to understand why.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `s.erase(s.begin(), std::remove_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), mayberemove).base())` when `reverse = true`

Comment: A good way to better look at what's going on would be to add something like `if (notok) { cout << 'r';} cout << ch;`. Do this right and the same lambda should work for both. I'm thinking something like `[&ok](char ch) { if (ch != '-') { ok = false; } return ok; };`

Comment: That said, this is probably way more work than you need to do as it always scans the whole string even though its job is almost always done fairly early.

Comment: @user4581301 I was think that too. It's not as efficient, but I got stuck just wanted to get it to work for for my own edification.

Comment: Pretty much what I figured. Going in the wrong direction you still learn something you can apply later. Often it's, "Well, I won't do that again!" but there are some gems.

Comment: @user4581301 God I had a lot of typos in that comment. Glad you could read through them.