# Remove first and last instance of a char from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a .ini file and in it i declare Sections like:

> [SectionName]

I want to get rid of '[' and ']' to just read in the SectionName, currently i'm using this to achieve what i want:

```
line.substr(1, line.size() - 2);
```

But this gets only rid of the first and last Character, no matter what they are. I'm looking for an elegant way to delete the first occurrence of '[' and last occurrence of ']'. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I tried using this:

```
void TrimRight(std::string str, std::string chars)
{
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(chars) + 1);
}

void TrimLeft(std::string str, std::string chars)
{
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(chars));
}

TrimLeft(line, "[");
TrimRight(line, "]");
```

But this is not removing them, for some weird reason...

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if the string is something like `Section[Name]`? Or `[Section]Name`? Or `A[Section]Name`? All contrived examples but they highlight corner cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trim matching characters from start or end of string c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479513/trim-matching-characters-from-start-or-end-of-string-c)

Comment: @Steve do you have a way to only delete it if those are on the outside of the string and first and last instance!?

Comment: @SupaDupa so you want my 3 examples to return `[Name]`, `[Section]` and `[Section]`, respectively?

Comment: @Steve No, as far as I can understand from the latest comment by SupaDupa , the expected behavior should be to remove only if '[' and ']' are in the beginning and at the end of the string, respectively.

Comment: Which means that this question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @ilim Not quite, that question is about removing from the start **or** end, not both if some condition is met.

Comment: @SupaDupa you're not passing a reference to TrimLeft and TrimRight. That is why the passed instance of std::string is passed by value, and the original object instance is not altered.

Comment: @Steve That is your honest opinion?! Any difference between those two questions could be remedied rather trivially, with some effort and googling by the OP.

Comment: @ilim Yes, they could, but that doesn't make this question an exact duplicate of that one. That answer is certainly applicable here and it's useful to refer to it.

Comment: @Steve You yourself pointed out above that the question lacks proper details such as what sort of texts are to be trimmed/handled in the desired manner. I believe OP did not look hard enough for a solution before posting this. If he/she did, then the question I referenced would have come up. OP could then fail to adapt that solution and could ask a separate question, but that is apparently not what happened. Anyhow... In essence, I believe the similarities between the two questions are too much to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the strings [front()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) member functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "[Section]";
    if (s.front() == '[' && s.back() == ']') {
        s.erase(0, 1);
        s.pop_back();
    }
    std::cout << s;
}
```

or if you want either removed:

```
if (s.front() == '[') {
    s.erase(0, 1);
}
if (s.back() == ']') {
    s.pop_back();
}
```

The [.pop_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) 
function removes the last character. Your functions are accepting arguments by value, not reference. Here are the function variations:

A `void` function where you pass the parameter by reference:

```
void trimstr(std::string& s) {
    if (s.front() == '[' && s.back() == ']') {
        s.erase(0, 1);
        s.pop_back();
    }
}
```

and the function that returns a `std::string`:

```
std::string gettrimmed(const std::string& s) {
    std::string temp = s;
    if (temp.front() == '[' && temp.back() == ']') {
        temp.erase(0, 1);
        temp.pop_back();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `string::find_first_of()` and `string::find_last_of()` to find the positions of the two characters. Then get the substring between those two positions:

```
int main() {
    std::string s("[SectionName]");
    size_t first = s.find_first_of('[');
    size_t last = s.find_last_of(']');
    if (std::string::npos != first && std::string::npos != last)
    {
        std::cout << s.substr(first + 1, last - first - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/k40IWv)

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvote just to be consistent string::npos != first && string::npos != last could be  std::string::npos != first && std::string::npos != last

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't match the clarification the OP provided in the comment.

Comment: Dear OP, comments are no place to modify requirements. Kindly edit your question.

Comment: They weren't modified - they were unclear and clarified in the comments

Comment: "I'm looking for an elegant way to delete the first occurrence of '[' and last occurrence of ']'." Now he/she is not.

Comment: It was phrased poorly but given the context of parsing sections in a .ini file there was a clear ambiguity.