# How to trim Platform::String myString = " answer " in c++/cx

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I want to trim string in c++/cx and I am using Platform::String

```
Platform::String myString = "  answer "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Platform::String` is a wrapper around the Windows Runtime `HSTRING` type, which is immutable. You should ideally use `Platform::String` only in the public interfaces of Windows Runtime Components, which require it, but otherwise consider `std::wstring` for operations that modify the string such as trimming.

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/strings-c-cx) states:

> In your C++ module, use standard C++ string types such as wstring for any significant text processing, and then convert the final result to Platform::String^ before you pass it to or from a public interface. It's easy and efficient to convert between wstring or wchar_t* and Platform::String.

You could use the following code to convert from `Platform::String` to `wstring`, then trim and then convert create new `Platform::String` from the result:

```
Platform::String^ myString = ref new Platform::String(L"  answer ");
//convert to wstring
std::wstring classicString(myString->Data());

//trimming
classicString.erase(0, classicString.find_first_not_of(' '));
classicString.erase(classicString.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);

//convert to Platform::String
Platform::String^ modifiedString = ref new Platform::String(classicString.c_str());
```

For more involved solutions to trimming a `wstring` refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring).