# How to read an input string in c++, ignoring spaces

Tags: c++, string, cin

My task is to create a program that converts one unit of measurement to another. So if the user enters 5 kg, it converts this to the equivalent in pounds. The requirements state that the user input must be read all on one line and any number of spaces anywhere in the input must not eliminate functionality. My problem is this: if a user enters their input with a bunch of spaces between the actual double 'mass' value and then in between different words in the unit of measurement such as 'short tonnes', how can I eliminate the spacing so that it reads as just "shorttonnes"?
So far my code is:

```
double mass;  string unit;
    cout << "Enter mass: ";
    cin >> mass;
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> unit;

    if (unit == "short tonnes" || unit == "sh tn")
    {
        //convert to long tonnes
    }
```

My code works to ignore white space before the double mass value is entered, as well as to ignore white space up until the first part of the string is entered. But I can not figure out how to make my program read "short tonnes" as just "shorttonnes" (regardless of the number of spaces between the words), so that I can do the string comparison and convert the mass value as necessary. Thank you in advance for your help and please do not hate on me, I am in my first week of learning C++.

Comment: Try `std::getline`.

Comment: Mis-read your requirement. Apologies.

Comment: I have also tried getline, however, this causes any spacing in between the numerical value and the start of the string to be interpreted as the unit and therefore nothing is read into the unit variable.

Comment: You want to trim the read-in string - here are [numerous answers of varying complexity to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216823/1270789).

Comment: Thank you @KenY-N I will look into these.

Comment: I'm not sure it is obvious, but `"short tonnes"` has a space in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My apologies again. Post edit, I think my initial comment was correct-ish. Get the line with `getline` as recommended by others. Then put the line in a `std::istringstream`. Read the words from the `stringstream` with `>>` and concatenate them with the `+` operator until you have assembled one of the tokens you are looking for. `>>`'s default behaviour is to discard all whitespace for you.

So...

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(cin, line)) // reads in a line
{
    std::istringstream stream(line);
    std::string spaceless;
    std::string word;
    while (stream >> word) // get words on the line without any whitespace
    {
        spaceless += word; // assemble without spaces
        if (spaceless ==  "shorttonnes")
        {
            //do something with spaceless
        }
        else if (spaceless ==  "Someothertoken")
        {
            // do something else with spaceless
        }
        else if ( ... ) 
        {
            // rinse, repeat
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple, stripped down example of just the concatenation: https://ideone.com/hGLr6f

There are other techniques you can use in place of the `if`/`else if` chain. A `std::map` of strings and function pointers for one, but that is another question.

Comment: Wow! That seems to have worked, just need to tweak a little bit for my needs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SabrinaTessier welcome to stack overflow. please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem : )

Comment: So grateful for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

`std::copy_if()` is another way to do what you want.  It's well worth learning how it works, since it can find uses in many other places, other than this particular problem.

If you write this space removal routine, it'll become a component you can re-use if you ever have to solve this problem again in a different situation.

```
void StripSpaces(std::string &str)
{
    std::vector<char> temp;
    temp.resize(str.length());
    auto pred = [] (char &c)
    {
        return c != ' ';
    };
    auto temp_end = std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), temp.begin(), pred);
    str = std::string(temp.begin(), temp_end);
}
```

That does an inplace removal of spaces from your string.

The `vector<char>` is there to hold the resulting value.  It's first resized to be the length of the input string, knowing that the result can be no longer than the input.

`pred` is a lambda that just takes a single character as it's parameter and returns a `bool` that is true if and only if the character is not a space.

`std::copy_if` does the heavy lifting.  It'll copy characters from your source string to `temp`, but only if `pred` returns true for that character.  It returns an iterator that refers to the element one past the last character we copied.  This is, very conveniently usable as a synonym for `temp.end()` if you want to consider `temp` as holding the resulting string.

The last thing is to reconstruct the parameter `string` from the data in `temp`.

Comment: This is awesome! I will definitely keep this in mind later on as I gain a better understanding of C++. Right now i'm sad to say but a lot of what you wrote doesn't make much sense to me but as I continue to learn, I will come back to your post. Thank you for your help