# Delimiter at the start of a string

Tags: c++, string, vector, delimiter, stringstream

I am splitting a string into smaller pieces based off of the delimiter `"/"`.

```
stringstream ss(stringToSplit);
string item;
vector<std::string> splitStrings;
while (std::getline(ss, item, delimiter))
{
   splitStrings.push_back(item);
}
```

some of the strings strings look like this:

```
home/user/folder
/home/user/folder
banana/grape/onion
/banana/grape/onion
```

The problem I am having is that the strings that have my delimiter `"/"` in the front are creating an empty item at the start of the resulting vector.  Is there a way to avoid this or to remove the empty item?
I have tried removing all `" "` strings in the vector but they still remain.

Comment: What hinders you to inspect `item` if the first character is a `/` delimiter, and strip it off (e.g. using `substr()`)?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ:  That would work, I'm not sure why I didn't even think of that.  I guess since I already asked, is there a way to do what I was originally trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just skip empty strings detected by `getline()` like this:

```
stringstream ss(stringToSplit);
string item;
vector<std::string> splitStrings;
while (std::getline(ss, item, delimiter))
{
   if(!item.empty()) { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
       splitStrings.push_back(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank You.

Comment: @Kirby You might need to consider whitespaces in the input as well. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)'s some information how to do that efficiently.