# LeetCode 65: Valid Number (C++)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, boost

I'd like to trim left/right the `input_string` before passing it to `regex_match` in the `if` statement and I've unsuccessfully tried the [boost `trim_right` and `trim_left`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216883/6553328), not sure how to solve it though.

How do I simply trim the inputs so that the first two inputs `"  0  "` and `"  0.1  "` would become valid numbers?

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> string_vector = {"   0  ","   0.1   ","abc","1 a","2e10","-90e3","1e","e3","6e-1","99e2.5","53.5e93","--6","-+3","95a54e53"};

    regex expression_two("^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+$|^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)$|^[+-]?[0-9]+$");

    for (const auto &input_string: string_vector) {
        if (std::regex_match(input_string, expression_two))
            cout << "[0-9] Char Class: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Current Output

```
[0-9] Char Class: '2e10' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '-90e3' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '6e-1' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '53.5e93' is a valid number.
```

#### Desired Output

```
[0-9] Char Class: '  0  ' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '  0.1  ' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '2e10' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '-90e3' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '6e-1' is a valid number.
[0-9] Char Class: '53.5e93' is a valid number.
```

Comment: Allow for spaces before and after the interesting pattern, `regex expression_two(R"aw(^ *([+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+|[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]+)|[+-]?[0-9]+) *$)aw");`

Comment: You're welcome.  Nathan's answer for trimming is spot on, as is the cross-reference to the other question.  I use Boost, but some people find Boost to be a bit too big (or daunting?) to want it in their projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue is that [`std::regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) needs a persitant string object for the results to refer to.  If you don't have that then after inspecting the results would be accessing a string that doesn't exist which is undefined behavior.  That means you need to modify the loop to use `trim_copy` from [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring) like

```
for (const auto &input_string: string_vector) {
    auto trimmed = trim_copy(input_string);
    if (std::regex_match(trimmed, expression_two))
        cout << "[0-9] Char Class: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;
}
```

This is going to cost you a copy, but it is the only way to do this without modifying the source data.  If you can modify the source data then you can use

```
for (auto &input_string: string_vector) {
    if (std::regex_match(trim(input_string), expression_two))
        cout << "[0-9] Char Class: '" << input_string << "' is a valid number." << endl;
}
```

instead.

Comment: @Emma Just change your for loop to the first one that I have in the answer, and copy the trim functions over from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring).  You can see it running [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39ed0e0403501865)