# C++ getline - Extracting a substring using regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, getline

I have a file with contents like this -

```
Random text
+-------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
|     Data          |   A  |   B   |     C     |   D   |
+-------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
|   Data 1          | 1403 |     0 |      2520 | 55.67 |
|   Data 2          | 1365 |     2 |      2520 | 54.17 |
|   Data 3          |    1 |     3 |      1234 | 43.12 |
Some more random text
```

I want to extract the value of column `D` of row `Data 1` i.e. I want to extract the value `55.67` from the example above. I am parsing this file line by line using **getline** -

```
while(getline(inputFile1,line)) {
    if(line.find("|  Data 1") != string::npos) {
        subString = //extract the desired value
}
```

How can I extract the desired sub string from the line. Is there any way using boost::regex that I can extract this substring?

Comment: I would just filter |. After the fifth | in a line you desired value.

Comment: First thing the .find()  works if you just say "Data 1". you don't have to put all spaces.

Comment: To get it You already know how much char you have for the last '|' before 55.67 o just use .substring(position of the lest '|'); and it will take from that to the end. after that you just throw all spaces! (take a look to substring man)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `regex` may have its uses, it's probably overkill for this.

Bring in a [`trim`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring) function and:

```
char delim;
std::string line, data;
int a, b, c;
double d;

while(std::getline(inputFile1, line)) {
    std::istringstream is(line);
    if( std::getline(is >> delim, data, '|') >>
        a >> delim >> b >> delim >> c >> delim >> d >> delim) 
    {
        trim(data);

        if(data == "Data 1") {
            std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ' ' << d << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8F8Rkq)

Comment: Thanks. This is quite a simple solution. Regex would make it quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is easily possible to extract your substring with a regex. There is no need to use boost, you can also use the existing C++ regex library.

The resulting program is ultra simple.

We read all lines of the source file in a simple for loop. Then we use `std::regex_match` to match a just read line against our regex. If we have found a match, then the result will be in the `std::smatch`   sm, group 1.

And because we will design the regex for finding double values, we will get exactly what we need, without any additional spaces.

This we can convert to a double and show the result on the screen. And because we defined the regex to find a double, we can be sure that `std::stod` will work.

The resulting program is rather straightforward and easy to understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

// Please note. For std::getline, it does not matter, if we read from a
// std::istringstream or a std::ifstream. Both are std::istream's. And because
// we do not have files here on SO, we will use an istringstream as data source.
// If you want to read from a file later, simply create an std::ifstream inputFile1

// Source File with all data
std::istringstream inputFile1{ R"(
Random text
+-------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
|     Data          |   A  |   B   |     C     |   D   |
+-------------------+------+-------+-----------+-------+
|   Data 1          | 1403 |     0 |      2520 | 55.67 |
|   Data 2          | 1365 |     2 |      2520 | 54.17 |
|   Data 3          |    1 |     3 |      1234 | 43.12 |
Some more random text)" 
};

// Regex for finding the desired data
const std::regex re(R"(\|\s+Data 1\s+\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\|)");

int main() {

    // The result will be in here
    std::smatch sm;

    // Read all lines of the source file
    for (std::string line{}; std::getline(inputFile1, line);) {

        // If we found our matching string
        if (std::regex_match(line, sm, re)) {

            // Then extract the column D info
            double data1D = std::stod(sm[1]);

            // And show it to the user.
            std::cout << data1D << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

For most people the tricky part is how to define the regular expression. There are pages like [Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/). There is also a breakdown for the regex and a understandable explanation.

For our regex

```
\|\s+Data 1\s+\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\|
```

we get the following explanation:

```
\|  
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s+
    matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    Data 1 matches the characters Data 1 literally (case sensitive)
\s+
    matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\| 
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
.*?
    matches any character (except for line terminators)
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\| 
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
.*?
    matches any character (except for line terminators)
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\| 
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
.*?
    matches any character (except for line terminators)
\| 
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s*
    matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

1st Capturing Group ([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)

\s*
    matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
\| 
    matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
```

By the way, a more safe (more secure matching) regex would be:

```
\|\s+Data 1\s+\|\s*?\d+\s*?\|\s*?\d+\s*?\|\s*?\d+\s*?\|\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s*\|
```