# C++ enter key on console with empty line not registering

Tags: c++

I noticed if when prompted to enter my choice, if I press enter (creating an empty line) it didn't detect my input as a 0 length input but rather it just allowed me to enter on the next line down. How do I stop this in an easy way so even if its an empty input it still registers

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string MMOption; //Main Menu Option
    std::cout << "Main Menu" << std::endl;
    while (MMOption != "6") {
        std::cout << "1. New Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. View Account/s" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. Edit Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. Delete Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. Option's" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6. Exit" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> MMOption;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused. Your code doesn't seem to be reading any input at all.

Comment: @cigien Ah sorry accidently missed a line, all good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
std::cin >> MMOption;
```

you can do:

```
std::getline(std::cin, MMOption);
```

which will read empty lines as well. [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) needs `#include <string>` as well.

Comment: for some reason std::getline(std::cin, MMOption); gives a error under the getline bit saying, namespace std has no member "getline"

Comment: @Evorage You need `<string>` I've edited the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you this solves it, il accept your answer once the cooldown is finished

Answer (score 2):

By default input using `>>` skips (reads and discard) any leading white-space, which includes newlines.

To detect empty lines as input you need to read full lines, for example using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then check if it's empty or not.

Note that if the user input leading spaces (normal space, tab, etc.) then it will be added in the string read by `std::getline`, and you need to strip or trim such leading spaces. And maybe trailing spaces as well. See e.g. [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring/217605#217605) for how to trim leading/trailing spaces from a string.

Comment: for some reason std::getline(std::cin, MMOption); gives a error under the getline bit saying, namespace std has no member "getline"

Comment: @Evorage You probably don't `#include <string>`

Answer (score 1):

By default, this will not get any empty values if you press return.

```
        std::cin >> MMOption;
```

However, you can opt in to use the Standard Get Line method. Which is `std::getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string MMOption; //Main Menu Option
    std::cout << "Main Menu" << std::endl;
    while (MMOption != "6") {
        std::cout << "1. New Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. View Account/s" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. Edit Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. Delete Account" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. Option's" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6. Exit" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, MMOption);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Check out this link for the online demo
http://cpp.sh/3pwze

Comment: at the top wouldn't I need #include <string>?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Even though the online compiler doesn't need it, you'd need to include it since getline is found inside the string library. I'll update the answer code.