# Delete tabs as well as spaces in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote the following c++ code which removes spaces from beginning and end of a string, But the problem with it is that it doesn't remove tabs, how may I fix that?

Plus, is there anything similar to tabs and spaces? (I am reading lines from file)

```
string trim_edges(string command) {
    const auto command_begin = command.find_first_not_of(' ');
    if (command_begin == std::string::npos)
        return "";

    const auto strEnd = command.find_last_not_of(' ');
    const auto strRange = strEnd - command_begin + 1;

    return command.substr(command_begin, strRange);
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring) and [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)

Answer (score 7):

`find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of` can also take a string as a set of characters to skip:

```
const auto command_begin = command.find_first_not_of(" \t");
const auto strEnd = command.find_last_not_of(" \t");
```

Comment: what the full code will look like? it seems you deleted return ""

Comment: Thanks, is there anything similar to spaces that need to e removed? like tabs and so on?

Comment: You could draw inspiration from [std::isspace](https://devdocs.io/cpp/string/byte/isspace)

Comment: @daniel For ASCII you could probably remove all chars `<= ' '` - otherwise, `"\a\b\f\n\r\t\v "` - See [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: @TedLyngmo what are those \a\b they aren't mentioned

Comment: They are mentioned in the link @TedLyngmo posted.