# Calling a function with default arguments

Tags: c++, function, sorting, dictionary, c++11

```
void Sort()
{
    vector<int> data;

    string number;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, number);

    data = insertion_sort(number);
    // ASCENDING
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << " ";
    }
    // // DESCENDING
    // for (int i = data.size()-1; i >=0 ; i--)
    // {
    //     cout << data[i] << " ";
    // }
}

int main()
{
    map<string, function<void()>> functions;
    functions["SORT"] = Sort;
    functions["IS_SORTED"] = Is_Sorted;
    functions["GETMAX"] = GetMax;
    functions["APPEND"] = AppendSorted;
    functions["GET_HISTOGRAM"] = GetHistogram;

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        string func;
        cin >> func;
        if (functions.find(func) != functions.end())
        {
            functions[func]();
        }
        cout << endl ;
        num--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want my `Sort()` function to be like this: `Sort(descending=False)`. And in the input, users can ask if they want descending or ascending, and if they didn't say, the function should be ascending by default. For example:

input:

```
2
SORT
1 -2 13 24 -100
SORT DESCENDING
1 2 3 5 6
```

output:

```
-100 -2 1 13 24
6 5 3 2 1
```

Comment: Yes, fine, and did you try `void Sort(bool descending=false)`?

Comment: Then what?...How should i get descending or ascending in this ''' functions["SORT"] = Sort;'''part?

Comment: Have you tried using a class?

Comment: You can't get that into functions["SORT"] unless you put it into all functions. You should probably split the command at the first " " and pass the remainder as option to the functions. Each function can then decide if it can use the argument or give an error. PS: you can make a wrapper function to reject extra args and use that on all but sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default values for parameters in C++.

You just have to define the function like:

```
void sort(bool descending = false) {...}
```

This way, when you call this function with no parameters, it will use the default value, and when you pass a value, the function will use yours.

**Notes**:

- You can't define any default parameter before a non-default parameter.

  ```
  void sort(bool descending = true, bool reverse); // Error!!
  ```
- You also can't overload this function with another one that has the same non-default parameters (the compiler won't know which one to use).

  ```
  void sort(bool descending = false); // OK
  void sort(); // Error!!
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `std::function<void()>` does not allow you to pass any input parameters to `Sort()` (or the other functions).  As such, `Sort()` (and the other functions) will have to check the user input for extra parameters before parsing data, eg:

```
void Sort()
{
    vector<int> data;

    string params;
    getline(cin, params);
    params = trim(params); // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/

    string numbers;
    getline(cin, numbers);

    data = insertion_sort(numbers);

    if (params == "DESCENDING")
    {
        // DESCENDING
        for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ASCENDING
        for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    map<string, function<void()>> functions;
    functions["SORT"] = Sort;
    functions["IS_SORTED"] = Is_Sorted;
    functions["GETMAX"] = GetMax;
    functions["APPEND"] = AppendSorted;
    functions["GET_HISTOGRAM"] = GetHistogram;

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        string func;
        cin >> func;

        auto it = functions.find(func);
        if (it != functions.end())
        {
            it->second();
        }
        cout << endl;

        --num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/gBQJmO)

Otherwise, the main loop will have to read in input parameters and pass them to the functions, eg:

```
void Sort(const string &params)
{
    vector<int> data;

    string numbers;
    getline(cin, numbers);

    data = insertion_sort(numbers);

    if (params == "DESCENDING")
    {
        // DESCENDING
        for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ASCENDING
        for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    map<string, function<void(const string&)>> functions;
    functions["SORT"] = Sort;
    functions["IS_SORTED"] = Is_Sorted;
    functions["GETMAX"] = GetMax;
    functions["APPEND"] = AppendSorted;
    functions["GET_HISTOGRAM"] = GetHistogram;

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        string func;
        cin >> func;

        auto it = functions.find(func);
        if (it != functions.end())
        {
            string params;
            getline(cin, params);
            it->second(trim(params));
        }
        else
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << endl;

        --num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/MP8LeV)